# How convert time to specific timezone on windows in C++?

Tags: c++, timezone

Have a Unix timestamp and I need equivalents of localtime_s, but where I can pass in the timezone. Alternately I'm looking for a way to change the timezone programatically for the app (not the whole system), so that localtime_s returns the correct values.

Strangely enough, if I set TZ environment variable in a shell to GMT, and then launch my application, localtime_s returns values in GMT.

I've tried:

```
::SetEnvironmentVariable("TZ", "GMT");
tzset();
```

But it does not change the results of later calls to localtime_s

Note that I'm running the application on Windows 7, using VS 2013.

Comment: You probably need to use a proper DateTime library. [boost.datetime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/date_time.html) might be your best bet.

Comment: VS-2015?  VS-2013?

Comment: @HowardHinnant, VS 2013. How would that effect your answer?

Comment: Boost time zone support is not very good, and poorly maintained.

Comment: What kind of time zone information do you have?  A Windows ID?  An IANA/Olson ID?  A POSIX string?  A numeric offset?

Comment: @MattJohnson - We currently would need to support eastern standard, central and GMT for starters. We would be fine using IANA/Olson, i.e. America/New_York, America/Chicago,  Etc/GMT

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a [free, open-source 3rd party library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), this works on VS-2013.  There are many examples on how to use it here:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes

For example here is how to output the current time in New York and Chicago:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Current time in New York: "
              << date::make_zoned("America/New_York", now) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Current time in Chicago : "
              << date::make_zoned("America/Chicago", now) << '\n';
}
```

This just output for me:

```
Current time in New York: 2016-08-12 10:36:24.670966 EDT
Current time in Chicago : 2016-08-12 09:36:24.670966 CDT
```